# Error in running C Program I found in a text book using Xcode.

Tags: c

I have literally written this code exactly as it is in the textbook I am using to learn C.  I'm not sure what these errors mean or where to begin.  Please help.  I am using Xcode.

```
//  Specific Age Calculator
//
//  Created by Christopher Pettit on 10/11/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Christopher Pettit. All rights reserved.

#include <stdio.h>
#define TARGET_AGE 88

int year1, year2;

int calcYear(int year1);


int main(void)
{
    // Ask the user for their birth year
    printf("What year were you born?\n");
    printf("Enter as a 4-digit year (YYYY) " );
    scanf(" %d", &year1);

    // Calculate the future year and display it
    year2 = calcYear(year1);

    printf("Since you were born in %d, you will be %d in %d. ", 
    year1,TARGET_AGE,year2);

    return 0;

    // This function to get the future year
    int calcYear (int year1);

 {
    return (year1+TARGET_AGE);
 }

}
```

[This is the error that Xcode produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY5Kv.png)

Comment: `int calcYear (int year1);` <- remove the semicolon (in the second time it is  appearing)

Comment: Are you sure you want to define a `calcYear` function inside the `main` body?

Comment: If that was copied *exactly* from a textbook, then that texbook has serious problems.  Otherwise, you didn't transcribe it correctly.  Go back over your code and the code in the book line by line.  If it turns out you did transcribe it accurately, then I'd recommend looking for a new textbook.

Comment: I don't really understand the down-vote from whoever did it.  I'm glad you all have a million points and sit up there on your high horses.  If there is a forum or somewhere else I should go to ask my questions then please point me in that direction.  Otherwise, I went through the steps of putting this question in the right "format" and spent at least 30 mins trying to look at documentation and fix the issue myself.  If this grip doesn't apply to you thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @ChristopherPettit: not the downvoter, but you lose a point with me for posting a link to a picture of the error, rather than including it in the text of your question.  Clicking random links isn’t safe, and some may be blocked if we’re reading from work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly braces are misplaced.
Thereby, function `calcYear` is not defined as it is hidden in `main`.

Without interpreting the meaning of your program, just to fix the linker error which says that there is no definition of `calcYear`, the code could look like:

```
    return 0;
}  // this one inserted

    // This function to get the future year
    int calcYear (int year1)   // ; this semicolon was deleted

 {
    return (year1+TARGET_AGE);
 }

//}  this one deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` function:

```
int calcYear (int year1);

{
   return (year1+TARGET_AGE);
}
```

Because of the semicolon, the compiler sees `int calcYear (int year1)` as another *declaration* (like the one before `main`), rather than the beginning of a function *definition*.  The next three lines are interpreted as a “naked” block within `main`.  Thus, `calcYear` is never properly defined, so the linker complains when it tries to build the binary.

Without the semicolon, the compiler would have interpreted it as a function *definition*, but C doesn’t allow you to define a function within another function; the compiler would have complained with a different error.

Move those lines outside the body of `main`, replace them with `return 0;`, and remove the semicolon after the function declarator:

```
  return 0;
}

int calcYear (int year1)
{
  return year1 + TARGET_AGE;
}
```

Like I said in my comment, if yours was an accurate transcription of the code in that textbook, then you need to find a different textbook.